# Using \DateTime to get next weekday including today

Tags: php, datetime

This is a little difficult to explain.

I have a task, that gets triggered once a week. The user specifies when that happens by choosing the day, hour, and minute of it.

When the task gets triggered, the execution time gets stored (`$lastDateTime`) and then one week would pass to get triggered again.

```
$day = 4;
$hour = 10;
$minute = 30;

$daynames = array(
    0 => 'Sunday',
    1 => 'Monday',
    2 => 'Tuesday',
    3 => 'Wednesday',
    4 => 'Thursday',
    5 => 'Friday',
    6 => 'Saturday',
);

$now = (new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($offset)));
$last = $lastDateTime;
$next = (new \DateTime(' ' . $daynames[$day], new \DateTimeZone($offset)))
        ->setTime($hour, $minute, 0);

if ($now > $next) {
   // trigger the task
}
```

The problem is that if today is the trigger day `$next` is the whole day in the past and so triggering is nonstop.

If doing this, i cant get the current day to be triggered:

```
$next = (new \DateTime('next ' . $daynames[$day], new \DateTimeZone($offset)))
        ->setTime($hour, $minute, 0);
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], so people can reproduce this? There's too many unknowns here. Also, give examples of current time/timezone and expected results.

Comment: The issue is very simple. When using `\DateTime('monday')->setTime(10, 30, 0)` mondays at evening, i still get the current day and not next monday.

Comment: Well, then [edit] your Q to reflect that! I should be able to copy'n'past this into a file and run it to see the issue.

Comment: Curious why you're not just adding 7 days to `$last`; your business logic is "triggers every **week**, based on a supplied day, hour and minute". https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: `if ($now > $next) {` makes no sense, it will never be true

Comment: `if ($now > $next)` workes fine. But @TimLewis suggestion is what i followed. It changes the whole approch a bit, but makes it also much simpler and since `last` always has a value, there should be no issues when switching to that approach.

Comment: Nice! If you've got a working solution, I'd recommend adding it as an answer below; it might help someone else out who's facing a similar problem. "Recurrences" based on a `$lastOccurrence` is a pretty common problem when working with scheduling applications 

Answer (score 1):

So what @TimLewis suggested was the simplest and best solution.
As i always have a `lastDateTime` timestamp value, i simply work with it like this:

```
$now = (new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($offset)));
$next = clone $lastDateTime;
$next->modify("+7 days")->setTime($hour, $minute, 0);

if ($now > $next) {
   // trigger the task
}
```

This can also be used very simple if you have other intervals than week:

```
// daily
$next->modify("+1 days");
$next->setTime($hour, $minute, 0);

// hourly
$next->modify("+1 hour");
$hourWithoutMinutes = (int) ($next)->format('H');
$next->setTime($hourWithoutMinutes, $minute, 0);

// minute intervalls
$next->modify("+{$interval} minutes");
```